# Creating UI Controls In Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net

Respected members,

i am new to mvc and i am presently facing problem to create my own textbox, button etc
and use it to store my data to database.

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [NerdDinner tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) first, if you are interested in pursuing ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Robert, based on the grammar and lack of complexity apparent in the original question, I'd say that your tutorial link and question about creating custom controls are a bit out of the OPs domain.